# background-image have incorrect position in firefox but in chrome is rightly

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

i have a problem with my background-image shadow in my content container. In Chrome is the background position rightly but in firefox wrong.

[image]

Here my Testsite: http://www.behringer-mauch.de/Tischler_Hehmann/index.php

I hope someone have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate background positions for x & y aren't approved in the CSS spec so

```
background-position-x: 80%;
background-position-y: bottom;
```

may work in Chrome but not in other browsers.

[**http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-position**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-position)

Comment: jep this is the solution: background-position: left 235px bottom 0px; THX

Answer (score 0):

use prefixes -moz- for mozilla firefox.

**Example**
`-webkit-linear-gradient` for Webkit based browsers (Chrome)

`-moz-linear-gradient` for Mozilla Firefox